# What species of plant is this? (Jasmine-like)

Tags: identification, flowers

Can someone help identify this plant? Thanks in advance. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these samples from a shrub in your yard or somebody's yard?  https://newfs.s3.amazonaws.com/taxon-images-1000s1000/Rosaceae/physocarpus-opulifolius-fl-gmittelhauser-a.jpg

Comment: Yes, I was given it by a neighbor to use in my project. The plant you provided looks very similar, although I don't see the traces of pink on my plant. Also, the leaves are kinda different. In your picture they are jagged.

Comment: Are these 4 petals or 5 petals?  Is this a shrub?  Vine?

Comment: 4 petals. It's a shrub.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the scent, I was given it when it was already severed for a while from the plant. I'd guess around 30-40 stamens per flower, but I do not have it on hand right now so I can check. Also, an additional piece of information, this was collected in south-central Europe. I see most Philadelphus species are native to North America. That kind of confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp I was in the ballpark.  I could be wrong as I am often.  I believe this is Philadelphus lewisii, Mock Orange.  It is native in Washington state.  [Philadelphus lewisii](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrT6VuS2SlZjVgAJj0nnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Philadelphus%20Lewisii&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002)

Answer (score 3):

It is [Philadelphus coronarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphus_coronarius#/media/File:Philadelphus_coronarius.jpg), a shrub with scented flowers. It has 4 petals and toothed leaves.

Comment: I'm glad you provided coronarius.  Good answer...

Comment: It may as well be this, but I think the other answer looks more like my sample. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: I think the veins in the leaves look more similar for lewisii.  Otherwise, they are so very alike.  Thanks Alina!